# prometheus-adapter empty item list but successful HTTP request

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I am using the following values.yaml for the prometheus-adapter Helm deployment:

```
rules:
  default: false
  custom:
  - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"go_routines_total"}'
    resources:
      overrides:
        job: {resource: "namespace"}
        queue: {resource: "service"}
    name:
      matches: ^(.*)
      as: "go_routines_total"
    metricsQuery: go_routines_total{job=~"rt-scrape"}
```

These are the responses I get for the kubectl checks:

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/" | jq .
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "namespaces/go_routines_total",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": false,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/*/metrics/go_routines_total" | jq .
{
  "kind": "MetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/%2A/metrics/go_routines_total"
  },
  "items": []
}
```

After increasing the prometheus-adapter verbosity to 10, I can confirm that the HTTP request to Prometheus is successful and the data (162) actually exists within the response:

```
I1018 13:33:05.254264       1 api.go:76] GET http://**.**.**.**:80/api/v1/query?query=go_routines_total%7Bjob%3D~%22rt-scrape%22%7D&time=1634563985.252&timeout= 200 OK                                                                                                        

I1018 13:33:05.254351       1 api.go:95] Response Body: {"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"vector","result":[{"metric":{"__name__":"go_routines_total","instance":"**.**.**.**:80","job":"rt-scrape"},"value":[1634563985.252,"162"]}]}}                               I1018 13:33:05.254743       1 httplog.go:104] "HTTP" verb="GET" URI="/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/%2A/metrics/go_routines_total" latency="21.148501ms" userAgent="kubectl/v1.21.3 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4" audit-ID="cae29c7f-6915-4b49-aee3-164bbfdede9e" srcIP="10.132.0.189:44084" resp=200
```

I am not sure why the value of "go_routines_total" (162) is not listed under "items" in the kubectl command. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding custom labels to the prometheus-operator:

```
prometheus: 
  prometheusSpec:
    serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
    serviceMonitorSelector: {}
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - job_name: 'scrape-job'
        metrics_path: '/api/v1/metrics'
        scrape_interval: 5s
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['http://**']
            labels:
              namespace: 'project'
              service: 'app-svc'
```